# Is it right to say "what is your travel source?"?

Tags: grammaticality, usage

Suppose you want to ask somebody where they intend to travel from and what their destination is, is it right to say: "what is your travel source and destination?"

Comment: If you want a "technical" term, consider "origin".

Comment: Thats it! I wonder why i didn't think of that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would understand *travel source* to be somewhere to get travel resources, it is not in common usage as the starting point or departure point for a journey. We would normally say "where are you leaving from" or where are you departing from".

Comment: Or "What is your point of departure?"